# Configure NFS server for systems in a Network

Tags: networking, fedora, vmware, nfs

I have installed nfs server using `yum -y install nfs-utils`. But I want to configure the 
NFS server service to export the /backups directory  as read-write to all systems in 
the 192.168.26.0 network. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You configure the NFS server export table with `exports` (`man exports`)

You can for example create the file `/etc/exports.d/backups` to contain

```
/backups 192.168.26.0(rw)
```

Reexport all synchronize the exports with `exportfs -r`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since it's read-write. So should it be ro or rw ? And do I run the command exportfs -r /etc/exports.d/backups to take effect ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread as read-only `(ro)`, it should be `(rw)` of course. No, you just run `exportfs -r`  as is to synchronize. See `man exportfs`